Correct way to make an unformatted and unmounted partition world writeable at boot?
So I have a bit of a special case.
After the machine boots up, I need one of the drives on the machine to have an unformatted partition that is world writable.
The reason: an application is building it's own filesystem on that partition.
The problem:
I've put together a systemd script that does a chmod a+rw /dev/$partition_name
If I check the permissions via stat or ls -l, the "other" writable permission looks good
e.g. it's brw-rw-rw-
HOWEVER, once the machine has booted up, the permissions have changed to:
brw-rw---.
So the questions:

why do the permissions keep flipping?
what is the correct way to do this?


Can you try "chmod 666 /dev/sdb_your_disc"


why do the permissions keep flipping?

Most likely it's udev applying standard permissions after its rule processing. In other words, your service runs too early as it hasn't declared the right dependencies so it races against other services.
Devices don't get created in an instant – there is a non-zero amount of time during which the device is being configured by udev (whether it's to change /dev node permissions or change hardware configuration or load firmware), and programs that want to use that device during startup are supposed to wait for the 'ready' event. For example, your service should have After=dev-sdc3.device if it uses /dev/sdc3.

what is the correct way to do this?

Use an udev rule to set permissions on device nodes.
ACTION!="remove", SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sd*", \
    ENV{ID_PART_TABLE_UUID}=="49d7b6f5-b6e0-4c67-9b33-217be62ecee9", \
    ENV{ID_PART_ENTRY_NUMBER}=="1", \
    <add match rules as needed>, \
    GROUP="myapp", MODE="0640"

(I'm sure your application doesn't need it to be world-readable and world-writable.)
